# Github actions reusable workflows currently does not support environments. Will my hack stop secrets from working?

Tags: github, github-actions, github-enterprise

I am using outputs on each job as a hack to enable Github environments to control if my reusable workflow runs.

My only concern is the "ENV_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID" & "ENV_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY". These secrets are environment specific. How does the reusable workflow know what secret I am passing in?

Is there a risk with the current setup it could get overwritten if two environments got ran at the same time?

```
name: Used to rollback docker containers

on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      tag_to_identify_containers:
        description: The last known containers prior to deployment
        type: choice
        required: true
        options:
          - last-known-testing
          - last-known-integrate
          - last-known-production
      new_tag_to_apply_to_containers:
        type: choice
        required: true
        options:
        - testing-latest
        - integrate-latest
        - production-latest


jobs:

  rollback_on_testing:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Rollback on testing
    outputs:
      signal_deployment: ${{ steps.step_id.outputs.environment }}

    environment:
      name: test
      url: https://test.###/

    steps:
      - id: step_id
        run: echo "::set-output name=environment::test"

  retag_and_rollback_test:
    needs: rollback_on_testing
    if: needs.rollback_on_testing.outputs.signal_deployment == 'test'
    uses: ###/###/.github/workflows/container-tagger.yml@main
    with:
      tag_to_identify_containers: ${{ github.event.inputs.tag_to_identify_containers }}
      new_tag_to_apply_to_containers: ${{ github.event.inputs.new_tag_to_apply_to_containers }}
      aws-region: eu-west-2
      run_cron_and_cycle_containers: true
    secrets:
      AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.SHARED_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
      AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.SHARED_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
      ENV_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.THIS_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
      ENV_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.THIS_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}

  rollback_on_integrate:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Rollback on Integrate
    outputs:
      signal_deployment: ${{ steps.step_id.outputs.environment }}

    environment:
      name: integrate
      url: https://integrate.###/

    steps:
      - id: step_id
        run: echo "::set-output name=environment::integrate"

  retag_and_rollback_integrate:
    needs: rollback_on_integrate
    if: needs.rollback_on_integrate.outputs.signal_deployment == 'integrate'
    uses: ###/###/.github/workflows/container-tagger.yml@main
    with:
      tag_to_identify_containers: ${{ github.event.inputs.tag_to_identify_containers }}
      new_tag_to_apply_to_containers: ${{ github.event.inputs.new_tag_to_apply_to_containers }}
      aws-region: eu-west-2
      run_cron_and_cycle_containers: true
    secrets:
      AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.SHARED_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
      AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.SHARED_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
      ENV_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.THIS_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
      ENV_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.THIS_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}


  rollback_on_production:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Rollback on Production
    outputs:
      signal_deployment: ${{ steps.step_id.outputs.environment }}

    environment:
      name: production
      url: https://###/

    steps:
      - id: step_id
        run: echo "::set-output name=environment::production"

  retag_and_rollback_production:
    needs: rollback_on_integrate
    if: needs.rollback_on_integrate.outputs.signal_deployment == 'production'
    uses: ###/###/.github/workflows/container-tagger.yml@main
    with:
      tag_to_identify_containers: ${{ github.event.inputs.tag_to_identify_containers }}
      new_tag_to_apply_to_containers: ${{ github.event.inputs.new_tag_to_apply_to_containers }}
      aws-region: eu-west-2
      run_cron_and_cycle_containers: true
    secrets:
      AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.SHARED_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
      AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.SHARED_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
      ENV_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.THIS_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
      ENV_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.THIS_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
```

[image]

Comment: See the [new (May 2022) keyword `secrets: inherit`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72103477/6309).

Answer (score 2):

An idea would be to use a matrix for your GitHub reusable workflow.

```
name: Reusable workflow with matrix strategy

on:
  push:

jobs:
  ReuseableMatrixJobForDeployment:
    strategy:
      matrix:
        stage: [test, integration, production]
    uses: octocat/octo-repo/.github/workflows/deployment.yml@main
    with:
      environment: ${{ matrix.stage }}
      tag_to_identify_containers: ${{ github.event.inputs.tag_to_identify_containers }}
      new_tag_to_apply_to_containers: ${{ github.event.inputs.new_tag_to_apply_to_containers }}
      aws-region: eu-west-2
      run_cron_and_cycle_containers: true
    secrets: inherit
```

When GitHub runs the workflow, your reusable workflow should have the environment "name" set to:

```
jobs:

  rollback_on_testing:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Rollback on testing
    outputs:
      signal_deployment: ${{ steps.step_id.outputs.environment }}

    environment:
      name: ${{inputs.environment}}
      url: https://test.###/
```

which should give you access to the environment's secrets inherited... "secrets: inherit".

Comment: Shouldn't you modify the reusable workflow so that it takes explicitly an input named `environment` for that solution to work?